# How to scroll JavaFX TextArea after setText

Tags: scroll, textarea, javafx, listener

I am using JavaFX and I want to scroll a textarea to a certain position from the top after I have set the text of the textarea first.

I have tried to first set a listener on my textarea and inside it I use `setText`:

```
    textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
        textArea.setScrollTop(<Here I use the scroll position that I want>);
    }
});
```

Then I try to set the text of the textarea by `setText`. But this does not scroll my textarea. I should add that I am loading in book long strings, but they load rather quickly. I have also tried to use a delay of 1 second inside the listener after I set the text and then scroll the textarea, and this turns out to work for me which might suggest that I use the wrong listener. I really want to be able to use a listener for this and not a delay.

All help is welcome!

Comment: Does it work if you wrap the scroll call with [`Platform.runLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)?

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if you use this code ?

```
textarea.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
        //textArea.setScrollTop(<Here I use the scroll position that I want>);
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code of the listener in a separate Thread to make the sleep and then call the textArea.setScrollTop using Platform.runLater, in this way the sleep doesn't block the Platform Thread. If you don't the Platform Thread is blocked by the sleep and any pending operation on the TextArea will be blocked as well, if any of the pending operation is preventing the scrolling it will not finish and your call will be voided.